# How to recover files form hide it pro app?

Tags: applications, external-sd, data-recovery, media-files

I had photos and videos hidden using `Hide it pro` app and I changed the memory location to `External SD card`. Three days back my SD card stopped working on my mobile but its working in pc. I recovered the videos from the program data folder. But the photos are just files now and not in the photo format. Its not opening. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to change the extension of the files to their original `*.png` or `*.jpg` extensions.  At least one of the extensions should work.